# scala groupby by the value of the map in a list of maps

Tags: scala, functional-programming

So I have a list of maps like this

```
val data = List(
           Map[String, String]("name" -> "Bob", "food" -> "pizza", "day" -> "monday"),
           Map[String, String]("name" -> "Ron", "food" -> "hotdog", "day" -> "tuesday"),
           Map[String, String]("name" -> "Tim", "food" -> "pizza", "day" -> "wednesday"),
           Map[String, String]("name" -> "Carl", "food" -> "hotdog", "day" -> "wednesday")
           )
```

I want to make a Map like this from that List of maps

```
val result = Map("pizza" -> Map("name" -> ("Bob", "Tim"), "day" -> ("monday", "wednesday")),
                 "hotdog"-> Map("name" -> ("Ron", "Carl"), "day" -> ("tuesday", "wednesday")))
```

How can I achieve this result? Thanks

*ps I'm a beginner in Scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a preliminary solution, there is probably an easier way of doing this with `fold` but I have to sketch that out separately

```
 data.groupMap(a => a("food"))(_.filter(_._1 != "food"))
   .map{
      case (a,b) => 
         (a, b.flatten.groupMapReduce(_._1)(a => List(a._2))(_ ++ _))}
```

1. You group the maps inside based on the value of `food`

This gives you:

```
Map(
  hotdog -> List(
               Map(name -> Ron, food -> hotdog, day -> tuesday), 
               Map(name -> Carl, food -> hotdog, day -> wednesday)), 
  pizza -> List(
               Map(name -> Bob, food -> pizza, day -> monday), 
               Map(name -> Tim, food -> pizza, day -> wednesday))
)
```

2. You remove the key `food` from the inner maps

```
Map(
  hotdog -> List(
               Map(name -> Ron, day -> tuesday), 
               Map(name -> Carl, day -> wednesday)), 
  pizza -> List(
               Map(name -> Bob,  day -> monday), 
               Map(name -> Tim,  day -> wednesday))
)
```

3. You "merge" the maps inside by using `groupMapReduce` which

   a) groups by the inner key (i.e. `name` and `day`)

   b) maps each value to a singleton list

   c) concats the lists

Edit: Here is a single pass solution using `foldLeft` but I don't think I like this any better. All the key accesses are unsafe and will blow up if your entry is missing the key. So ideally you would need to use `.get()` to get back an option and do bunch of pattern matching

```
data.foldLeft(Map[String, Map[String, List[String]]]())((b, a) => { 
  val foodVal = a("food")
  b.get(foodVal) match{
    case None => b + (foodVal -> 
        List("name" -> List(a("name")), "day" -> List(a("day"))).toMap) 
    case Some(v : Map[String, List[String]]) => 
      b + (foodVal -> 
        List("name" -> (v("name") :+ a("name")), "day" -> (v("day") :+ a("day"))).toMap)
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, what is the equivalent of groupMap in groupBy, because I use scala version 2.11.12 and groupMap is not available there

Comment: @derpyna `.groupBy(..).map(...).reduce(...)`  for the `groupBy` use the first two operations, for `groupMapReduce` all 3